# How to start uTorrent after Ubuntu update?

Tags: ubuntu, utorrent

Today uTorrent asked me if it could update, and I agreed. After some time, I realized that uTorrent was not going to run by itself.

I restarted Ubuntu. Now, when I run uTorrent it doesn't show any UI. However if I run it again I see a message box that it's already running. It seems to be stuck somewhere during the update process.

I'm running the Windows version through Wine.

Comment: If you run it from a terminal, do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very specific question about Wine and uTorrent.

You are probably more likely to find an answer to it [in the database of Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=11113) that describes all problems with Windows applications running in Wine on a certain version.

You should consider using a native Linux torrent client on Linux, or expect to be in the same position after the next update again.